# Realloc pointer points to random memory, crashes program

Tags: c, memory, realloc

My realloc statement in the second function works up until a point, then the pointer seems to point to random memory all of a sudden. Could someone please explain how I could fix this issue? Take a look at the output to possibly save yourself some time. 
Thank you.

```
int main()
{

    int testCases, i, n;
    int* primeArray;
    int* size;

    primeArray = malloc(sizeof(int));
    primeArray[0] = 2;
    size = 1;

    int number = 2;
    while(number < 1000){
        number = nextPrime(number, primeArray, &size);
        printf("Prime Array at %d is %d, size is %d, number is %d \n", 0, primeArray[0], size, number);
    }


    scanf("%d", &testCases);
    for(i = 0; i < testCases; i++){
        scanf("%d", n);

    }

    free(primeArray);
    free(size);
    return 0;
}
```

**Second Function:**

```
int nextPrime(int number, int* primeArray, int* size){
    int foundPrime = 0, num = number, i;
    while(!foundPrime){
        num++;
        int allNums = 0;
        //printf("Size: %d \n", *size);
        for(i = 0; i < *size; i++){
            //printf("%d mod %d \n", num, primeArray[i]);
            if(num % primeArray[i] != 0){
                allNums += 0;
            }
            else {
                allNums = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(allNums == 0){
            *size+=1;
            //printf("Size: %d \n", *size);
            foundPrime = 1;
            primeArray = realloc(primeArray, *size * sizeof(int) );
            primeArray[*size-1] = num;
            //printf("%d \n", primeArray[*size-1]);
            return num;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Prime Array at 0 is 2, size is 2, number is 3  
Prime Array at 0 is 2, size is 3, number is 5  
Prime Array at 0 is 2, size is 4, number is 7  
...  
Prime Array at 0 is 2, size is 94, number is 491  
Prime Array at 0 is 2, size is 95, number is 499  
Prime Array at 0 is 2, size is 96, number is 503  
Prime Array at 0 is 16852008, size is 97, number is 509
```

Comment: Certainly `int* size;...     size = 1;` generated a compiler warning.  Compile again with all warnings enabled.

Comment: Off topic - your loop in `nextPrime` could be made much faster if you skipped all the even numbers.  That is increment, `num` by 2 instead of `num++` on each iteration.  You can also terminate your loop early when `num > sqrt(primeArray[last]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`primeArray`, even though it's a pointer, is getting passed by value to your `nextPrime` function.  So if `realloc` changes the pointer value (as it can and often will), `main` doesn't get that value reflected back to it when `nextPrime` returns. A quick fix will be to change your `nextPrime` to take a pointer to a pointer parameter instead of just an array pointer.

Here's a quick fix where I modified the function signature of `nextPrime` and added code to the start and and end of the function.

```
int nextPrime(int number, int** ptrToPrimeArray, int* size){

    int* primeArray = *ptrToPrimeArray;  // primeArray is the deferenced value of ptrToPrimeArray

    int foundPrime = 0, num = number, i;
    while(!foundPrime){
        num++;
        int allNums = 0;
        //printf("Size: %d \n", *size);
        for(i = 0; i < *size; i++){
            //printf("%d mod %d \n", num, primeArray[i]);
            if(num % primeArray[i] != 0){
                allNums += 0;
            }
            else {
                allNums = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(allNums == 0){
            *size+=1;
            //printf("Size: %d \n", *size);
            foundPrime = 1;
            primeArray = realloc(primeArray, *size * sizeof(int) );
            primeArray[*size-1] = num;
            //printf("%d \n", primeArray[*size-1]);

            *ptrToPrimeArray = primeArray;   // return the changed value of primeArray back to the caller

            return num;
        }
    }
}
```

And then invoke it in `main` as follows:

```
number = nextPrime(number, &primeArray, &size);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the value returned by `realloc()` to a local variable, which is of course gone when the function `nextPrime()` returns. The value of `primeArray` in `main()` never changes.